# How to join two tables? mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Files table has

ID     Name    Surname

1      Tim        Smith

1      Ash        Donalds

---

Counter table has

ID    Count

1    50

2    800

---

I want to echo out the name surname from files table and counter tables using join mysql function in a table. Please help me.

Comment: Your ID must be different for Files. It looks great in Counter!

Comment: @clement, Yes my files id are different than the counter id. How can I related them together?

Comment: sandesh. Basically, if you have an ID to a table, the ID must be unique per table, so please put auto increment on it to avoid to have multiple records that has the same ID! If you want to link Files to Counter, you must use Foreighn Key, as @Bertrand said as response! you just have to add a new column in Files (if one file has one counter), and this conumn will reference the COunter ID. To select the files with counter associated, make the query as Bertrand ask with a quick edit, it will be good

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Files.Name, Files.Surname, Counter.Count
FROM Files, Counter
WHERE Files.ID = Counter.ID
```

OR

```
SELECT Files.Name, Files.Surname, Counter.Count
FROM Files
INNER JOIN Counter ON Files.ID = Counter.ID
```